# Workflow to protect against breaking changes in git submodules

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, project-structure, multiple-projects

We are currently refactoring code to be shared among different projects in our company. This shared code will be included in other projects as a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

One thing we're worried of is breaking changes introduced to the super project from the submodule at certain stages of the project (e.g: a point where we should be stable / code freeze).

I have never worked with submodules before, but according to what I know, a submodule references a particular commit in another repo, so you're basically OK as long as you don't update the submodule in the project.

Another teammate of mine suggested that whenever we enter a "stable phase" of the project (e.g: finish dev), we should create a branch of the submodule and point to that. I think this is an overhead and seems wrong (a shared project shouldn't be version-locked with other projects that use it).

**So, to sum it up, my questions are:**

1. Is there anything at all that should be done to protect a super project from submodules updates (breaking changes) ?
2. Is there a known workflow where a super project that goes into a stable phase, also creates a new branch of its submodules to point to? (a link would be great).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything at all that should be done to protect a super project from submodules updates (breaking changes) ?

No: whatever modifications are done in a submodule (and push to its upstream repo) would not affect the parent repo: it would still reference the same **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)).

> Is there a known workflow where a super project that goes into a stable phase, also creates a new branch of its submodules to point to?

No: a submodule is a fixed SHA1.